# JComboBox setText Method

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

javax.swing.JComboBox class does not support the setText method. Is there a way on how can I set the text of an editable combo box? Like something that I can call `jcombobox1.setText("Text has changed!");`

Comment: Are you looking to set the combo box's text to _any_ value, or one from the list of values in the model of the combo box?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you set the JComboBox to editable you can do this:

```
   String item = box.getEditor().getItem().toString();
```

To get the String the user typed or selected. And

```
  box.getEditor().setItem("Text Has Changed");
```

to set your own text.

Comment: Shouldn't that be setItem() (since the question wants to set the value) instead of getObject() (which is getItem() in Java 6)?

Comment: @Jerome That's right. I'll correct it. That's what you get for too much haste.

Comment: curious - which use-case do you have in mind that requires to go so dirty?

Answer (score 9):

You can set the selectedItem to whatever value you want:

```
 comboBox.setSelectedItem("text has changed");
```

Note that the selectedItem is explicitly documented to allow elements which are *not* part of the model.